# Stanford NER precedence

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford NER for training, I have 2 questions!

1)How do i give precedence to a particular class label.
for example if a "word" is trained as **Class A** and the same "word" is **Class B**, and when "word" is found in the text I want it to overcome the conflict and be labelled as **Class B** only, irrespective of how many occurrence "word" has when trained for **Class A**.

2)How to train a token with two words, for example "Mysore" is a **City** and "Mysore Road" is a **Road**. But in Stanford NER i need to train both "Mysore" and "Road" separately as **Road**, so there is a conflict for "Mysore" to be **City** or **Road**.

Comment: for second one you can try bigrams if any there in NER.

Comment: NER is sequence tagging progblem, not per-word classification, thus none of the above should be any problem (there are no such problems in NER). In particular Stanford NER is CRF (conditional random field) which **does not** tag a single word, it always uses **a context** to do that.